# Changing style in javascript on onclick

Tags: javascript, styles, togglebutton

I want to make a few simple buttons that toggle color each time they are pressed. With a button press also some unique string needs to be passed to the server. Therefore on every button press I run two functions. My problem is that when I run this script, button changes color to red only for the period after the alert message Msg1 is displayed. When I answer OK to the Msg2, the color of the button reverts back to green.
What am I doing wrong here?

```
<style>
.button { background-color: green; }
.buttonOn { background-color: red; }
</style>

<button id="r1" class="button" onclick="mF1(id)">Relay 1</button>

<script>

function mF1(btn) {
var property = document.getElementById(btn);
alert('Msg1: This is ' + property.className);
if (property.className == 'button')     
    { property.className = 'buttonOn' }
else 
    { property.className = 'button';  }
alert('Msg2: This is ' + property.className);
mF2(btn);            
}

function mF2(id) { window.location.href='?HVAC-' + id; }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using JavaScript to change the DOM.

Then you are setting `location.href` to a new value.

This causes a new page to load.

The new page does not have the modifications you made to the DOM.

---

You would need to write code that examines the query string when the page loads and sets the appropriate classes.

Comment: I only need to pass a parameter "HVAC.." to the server. No need to load any page. I thought "?" in the href string denotes that this is an HTTP query string, not a new page to load?

Comment: @ggv — A query string is part of a URL. Changing the query string changes the URL. Setting `location.href` to a different URL (unless you are only modifying the fragment identifier … which is never sent to the server) loads a new page.

Comment: You should use ajax in this case.

Comment: Quentin - Maybe this is stupid question, but I am trying to understand - do you mean that I have to send a query string to the server and the server then paints my button red if appropriate string is received? I can not do it in javascript on the client's machine?

Comment: @ggv — You can set it to red on the current screen. You've proven that. You can see it change colour. If you then replace the page with a new one then you've replaced the page that you turned the button red on. See also Ajax.

Comment: OK, I will have to study this. I am very new to HTML/javascript. Thanks!